# Insert div if background image exists

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have an object that may or may not have an image associated with it. If it does have an image, I want the image to be used as the background-image for a div. If it does not have an image, I don't want the div to show. I'm using django templates. Here's what I tried so far:

```
{% if post.image %}
    <div class="background"></div>
{% endif %}
```

And the CSS is:

```
.background{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("{{ post.image.url }}");
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

The images are stored in AWS S3. What's happening is that if the object doesn't have an image, the page doesn't load and tells me that the 'image' attribute has no file associated with it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation to your css also and render image only if it exists:

```
.background{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  {% if post.image %}background-image: url("{{ post.image.url }}");{% endif %}
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```